# Algorithm that finds n-th number coprime with a given one (inclusion - exclusion principle)

Tags: c++, performance, math

I've bumped into a problem that asks me to find the *n-th* number that is coprime with a given one (p).

The restrictions are:

- 1 ≤ n ≤ 12 000 000 000
- 1 ≤ p ≤ 10^14
- Time limit: 0,05 seconds

Now, the expected solution makes use of the inclusion and exclusion principle. Others that have solved this problem have a function that I can't figure out what it does, but I know it's supposed to be the one that makes use of this principle. If someone can explain the function, that'd be great.

Here's a full source from someone that has solved this problem:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int NMAX = 11e4 ;
bitset < NMAX + 5 > c ;
vector < int > primes ;
inline void sieve ( long long n ) {
    long long i, j, lim = ( long long ) sqrt ( ( double ) n ) ;
    c [ 0 ] = c [ 1 ] = 1 ;
    for ( i = 4 ; i <= n ; i += 2 )
        c [ i ] = 1 ;
    for ( i = 3 ; i <= lim ; i += 2 )
        if ( ! c [ i ] )
            for ( j = i * i ; j <= n ; j += i * 2 )
                c [ j ] = 1 ;
    primes.reserve ( 1e4 ) ;
    primes.push_back ( 2 ) ;
    for ( i = 3 ; i <= n ; i += 2 )
        if ( !  c [ i ] )
            primes.push_back ( i ) ;
}
long long factors [ 25 ], nr, med ;
inline void gen_fact ( long long x ) {
    long long d = 0, ok ;
    nr = 0 ;
    while ( primes [ d ] * primes [ d ] <= x && d < primes.size () ) {
        ok = 0 ;
        while ( x % primes [ d ] == 0 )
            x /= primes [ d ], ok = 1 ;
        if ( ok )
            factors [ ++ nr ] = primes [ d ] ;
        ++ d ;
    }
    if (x != 1)
        factors [++nr] = x;
}

inline long long numbers(long long x) {
    long long p, sign, i, j, cnt, ans = x ;
    for ( i = 1 ; i < ( 1 << nr ) ; ++ i ) {
        sign = 1 ;
        p = 1 ;
        cnt = 0 ;
        for ( j = 0 ; j < nr ; ++ j )
            if ( ( 1 << j ) & i ) {
                p *= factors [ j + 1 ] ;
                ++ cnt ;
            }
        if ( cnt % 2 )
            sign = - 1 ;
        ans += sign * x / p ;
    }
    return ans ;
}

int main() {
    ifstream in ( "frac.in" ) ;
    ofstream out ( "frac.out" ) ;
    long long n, p, st, dr, last, val ;
    sieve( NMAX ) ;
    in >> n >> p ;
    gen_fact ( n ) ;
    st = 0 ;
    dr = LLONG_MAX ;
    while ( st <= dr ) {
        med = ( st + dr ) >> 1 ;
        val = numbers ( med ) ;
        if ( val >= p )
            dr = med - 1, last = med ;
        else
            st = med + 1 ;
    }
    out << last ;
}
```

The function in question is `numbers()`.

As for the other functions, I understand them. The only explanation I need is how this function makes use of the inclusion - exclusion principle.

In combinatorics, the inclusion–exclusion principle is a counting technique which generalizes the familiar method of obtaining the number of elements in the union of two finite sets; symbolically expressed as
[Wikipedia MathJax render of expression](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/05f67b2ce4414f2a1f96e4210a86d71028aa53b6).

The full identity: [Wikipedia MathJax render of the identity](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/c14e130250afb7484a5162c7fc76fab425397279)

As for what I recognize in the function that uses the principle, the line `ans += sign * x / p` is the only thing I recognize.

What I understand from this principle is that, a way to find the elements of a reunion of sets, is to add all the elements of every single set into one big set, then from that big set, subtract the elements that 2 arbitrary sets from the ones given have in common, then add the elements that 3 arbitrary sets have in common, and so on. This is because the first time we added up all the elements, we also added up elements that might also be in at least another set that we have, and in a reunion, we only want them appearing once.

Comment: Edited the OP. I could actually use the explanation of the details of the function, including the basic ones. I literally don't understand much of it, because it probably introduces a new formula of some sort that I just can't figure out.

Comment: Decent edit. But please go into the details of the concept. Only if you phrase an explaantion yourself it is possible to gauge the level of understanding you have. (Also, but a minor side issue, StackOverflow users are not fans of linking externally.)

Comment: @Yunnosch Well, I'm not sure how I'm going to use MathJax in Stack Overflow. I can make use of it in Math Stack Exchange, but not sure about Overflow, this is why I linked.

Comment: @Yunnosch Re-edited, added my understanding.

Comment: I think you have now indeed focused on your specific problem, hence I revoked my close vote. Good luck.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for helping me with the phrasing!